# Is there a way to create a loop that adds rows to a table and moving content from one cell to another?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am creating storyboards from PowerPoint. I export the PowerPoint into a word document that creates a table with the notes in the column next to the thumbnail of the slide. I need the notes under the thumbnail. My solution is to add a row under Row 1 and move the content from Row 1, Column 3 to Row 2, Column 2.

The code I have works fine but a loop would be better instead of typing in every row to add and every cell to cut and paste.

```
Documents("Slide 1.docm").Tables(1).Rows(7).Select
Selection.InsertRowsBelow 1

Documents("Slide 1.docm").Tables(1).Rows(9).Select
Selection.InsertRowsBelow 1

Documents("Slide 1.docm").Tables(1).Cell(Row:=1, Column:=3).Select
Selection.Cut
Documents("Slide 1.docm").Tables(1).Cell(Row:=2, Column:=2).Select
Selection.Paste

Documents("Slide 1.docm").Tables(1).Cell(Row:=3, Column:=3).Select
   Selection.Cut
Documents("Slide 1.docm").Tables(1).Cell(Row:=4, Column:=2).Select
Selection.Paste

Documents("Slide 1.docm").Tables(1).Cell(Row:=5, Column:=3).Select
   Selection.Cut
Documents("Slide 1.docm").Tables(1).Cell(Row:=6, Column:=2).Select
Selection.Paste

Documents("Slide 1.docm").Tables(1).Cell(Row:=7, Column:=3).Select
   Selection.Cut
Documents("Slide 1.docm").Tables(1).Cell(Row:=8, Column:=2).Select
Selection.Paste

Documents("Slide 1.docm").Tables(1).Cell(Row:=9, Column:=3).Select
   Selection.Cut
Documents("Slide 1.docm").Tables(1).Cell(Row:=10, Column:=2).Select
Selection.Paste

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where possible, try to use the Range object instead of Selection. It's faster and more reliable. Cut and Paste is also slow and only needed if there is local formatting that needs to be preserved. With statements can also speed up your code and eliminate redundant code.

```
Sub MoveTableContent()
  With Documents("TableMoveData.docm").Tables(1)
    .Rows.Add BeforeRow:=.Rows(8)
    .Rows.Add BeforeRow:=.Rows(10)
    For x = 1 To .Rows.Count Step 2
      .Cell(Row:=x + 1, Column:=2).Range.Text = .Cell(Row:=x, Column:=3).Range.Text
      .Cell(Row:=x, Column:=3).Range.Text = ""
    Next x
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I thought I had put all of my code in but it is not showing. The rows being added need to loop also until every row has a blank row under it. The number of rows vary depending on the PPT they were exported from. So some have 42 rows and some have 50 plus rows. Thanks

Comment: I checked the code and the first row works properly with the thumbnail in row 1, column 2 and the text in row 2, column 2. But  in Row 3, column 2 (should have a thumbnail) is blank. The text did move to Row 4, Column 2.

Comment: Sorry, your comments are more confusing then enlightening. Your original question was how to create a _loop_. Feel free to modify the code I posted to meet your specific needs.

Comment: I appreciate your help. sorry for being confusing. I tried modifying the code. It worked but it also deleted the items I didn't want deleted. This is what I had  - Row 1, column 2 has a thumbnail image in it. Row 1, column 3 has text in it. I was trying to cut Row 1, column 3 (text) and paste the text in Row 2, column 2.

Comment: I modified the VBA to add _Step 2_ in the For loop. Then it will just work on every second row.